# What's wrong with this Query?

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with the following SQL query?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM ".TABLE." WHERE desgid='$id', weightid='$weightid' AND deptid='$deptid' ";
```

The error message is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '
>   weightid='12' AND deptid='31'' at line
>   1

Comment: 5 answers in less than 30 seconds... Good question :)

Comment: So many answers and not a single one mentioning SQL injection. Don't ever never concatenate SQL with untrusted user input. Use parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM ".TABLE." WHERE desgid='$id' AND weightid='$weightid' AND deptid='$deptid'
                                           ^
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the comma after the first `where` bit. Try

```
"SELECT * FROM ".TABLE." WHERE desgid='$id' AND weightid='$weightid' AND deptid='$deptid'"
```

Answer (score 2):

There was not AND, try this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM ".TABLE." WHERE desgid='$id' and weightid='$weightid' AND deptid='$deptid' ";
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `,` in your SQL code after `desgid='$id'` try changing this to `AND` so your SQL code says:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM ".TABLE." WHERE desgid='$id' AND weightid='$weightid' AND deptid='$deptid' ";
```

Answer (score 2):

The comma is your problem:

desgid='$id'`,` weightid =

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
WHERE desgid='$id', weightid='$weightid'
```

to

```
WHERE desgid='$id' AND weightid='$weightid'
```

and see.